# Patent with Multiple Claims

Tags: claims, multiple

Suppose a granted patent has four claims A,B,C and D.
Can someone do what the patent teaches using only A,B and C only without infringing the issued patent?
Ashok Mathur

Answer (score 3):

Patent claims are numbered. So if a patent has claims 1, 2, 3 and 4, you can infringe on the patent if you practice even just one of the claims. However, a claim might have multiple steps in it. So if claim 1 has step a, b, c and d, you need to practice each and every step to infringe on that claim.

Comment: Dear Eric  I find your answer very satisfactory.

Comment: @AshokChandMathur  Thanks. It would be great if you accept my answer by clicking the check mark.